# Is it possible to access a user's Twitter access token and secret with the Firebase Javascript SDK?

Tags: javascript, firebase, twitter, firebase-authentication

I'm using the Firebase Javascript SDK and currently have users able to sign up and into, as well as link from settings, their Twitter accounts. I'd like to present users with an option to share new posts to Twitter without having them have to do it manually.

Is it possible to grab a user's access token and secret so I can make a request like this to Twitter?

Currently I'm calling sign in with this code:

```
doSignInWithTwitter = () =>
    this.auth.signInWithPopup(this.twitterProvider);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It is in the result of `signInWithPopup`:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
  // This gives you a the Twitter OAuth 1.0 Access Token and Secret.
  // You can use these server side with your app's credentials to access the Twitter API.
  var token = result.credential.accessToken;
  var secret = result.credential.secret;
  // The signed-in user info.
  var user = result.user;
  // ...
}).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  // The email of the user's account used.
  var email = error.email;
  // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
  var credential = error.credential;
  // ...
});
```

Example taken directly from [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/twitter-login#handle_the_sign-in_flow_with_the_firebase_sdk).

Comment: Hi Michael. Is it possible to retrieve this is a user has linked their Twitter account but logs in with another form? Like if they link both their Google and Twitter but choose to log in one time with their Google?

Comment: Hey Dan, if a user has Twitter and Google linked to the same account and the user signs in with Google, you will only get the Google credentials as Firebase Auth does not store or manage 3rd party OAuth credentials. They only return what is available after the OAuth flow completes.

Comment: Got it! Realized the tokens don't expire and can just be saved and it made everything make way more sense/the docs code to work better. For any future users reading, just store the access token and secret and it doesn't matter how a user authenticates into your app.